# B4A send photo and text to telegram via intent

Tags: android, telegram

I have read a few examples, but I can't get it working with b4a

```
Dim share As Intent
share.Initialize(share.ACTION_SEND,"")
share.SetType("image/text/plain")
share.PutExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT","myText")
share.PutExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM",ParseUri(File.Combine(File.DirRootExternal, "Test.png")))
share.WrapAsIntentChooser("Share")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include SetPackage:

```
   Dim jo As JavaObject = share
   jo.RunMethod("setPackage", Array("org.telegram.messenger"))
```